# How does one output data using mySQL PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

New to mySQL PDO.  I have read other answers here and read tutorials and am finally taking the plunge.  Problem is I cannot seem to output data.  Hence, can someone assess my code to ensure it is correct?  Also, is the system I am using to query the db efficient and clean and secure?  thanks

```
$pdo --- the correct connection information is in this line but has been removed ---
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// SELECT sql query
try {
 $thedate='2013-06-03';
 $rotation=1;
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013 WHERE thedate=:thedate AND rotation=:rotation");
 $stmt->bindValue(':thedate', $thedate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindValue(':rotation', $rotation, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
}
catch(PDOException $ex) { 
 echo $ex->getMessage(); 
} 
while($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {  
 echo $rows['thedate'] . "\n";  
 echo $rows[assignedRad] . "\n";  
 echo $rows[rotation] . "\n";  
}

// close the connection
$pdo = null;
```

This code outputs nothing.  No errors.  Nothing at all.

By the way, the table exists and the SELECT * FROM works fine when I manually run the mySQL statement, so data does exist with this query.

Comment: try moving your while into your try block

Comment: You clearly don't have error reporting cranked up, since you have unquoted array keys that would issue undefined constant notices.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ... always in development...

Comment: Try the query `SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013 WHERE thedate='2013-06-03' AND rotation=1` from mysql command prompt (or phpmyadmin). Does it return records?

Comment: @Class, I moved the WHILE into the TRY block and still no output.

Comment: @hek2mgl, it returns the correct records.  Works fine in the mysql command prompt.

Comment: what does `var_dump($rows);` produce. If nothing is being outputted there something wrong with your query or bindvalues;

Comment: try to clear your browser cache.. and add the `'` quotes around array indexes

Comment: @Class, var_dump($rows) gives me bool(false)  ... what to do with that?

Comment: @hek2mgl, I have added the ' quotes.  done, no output.  no errors.  no difference.

Comment: +1, because this question does not deserve to be downvote. There are some problems with his code, but if he know what he is doing, then he won't come here and ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {  
 echo $rows['thedate'] . "\n";  
 echo $rows[assignedRad] . "\n";  
 echo $rows[rotation] . "\n";  
}
```

To

```
while($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {  
 echo $rows['thedate'] . "\n";  
 echo $rows['assignedRad'] . "\n";  
 echo $rows['rotation'] . "\n";  
}
```

---

**Debug 01**

Maybe you can try this to test whether you truly receive any data from database

```
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Instead of your while-loop

---

**Debug 02**
Try the simple query that you strongly believe there will be no SQL error for example:

> SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013

Without any value binding.

---

**Debug 03**

Try another query with WHERE condition, but no binding

```
SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013 WHERE thedate='2013-06-03' AND rotation=1
```

Comment: No output still.  The server has been working fine for a multitude of other scripts for years using PHP and mySQL with no recent server changes.

Comment: Try `print_r($stmt->fetchAll());` instead of your while-loop to test if you truly get any data from database

Comment: While the above might speed up the processing of the while loop it should be no different than using strings on his assoc array. PHP defaults to a string value if no constant is found for a certain key.

Comment: @francisco.preller, the point is not about speed up the process, it is about debug the problem why the poster code does not work. It is impossible to answer his question if we don't know if his query does return any row.

Comment: @invisal, when I get rid of the binds and use:  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013"); everything works fine. But when I add the parameters and bring back the bids then I get no output.  So that is the problem.  What is the solution?

Comment: Try other query. See Debug 03.

Answer (score 1):

You told that `var_dump($row)` gives you `FALSE`. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) says:

> The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, >FALSE is returned on failure.

Add the following line:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
 echo $row['thedate'] . "\n";  
 echo $row['assignedRad'] . "\n";  
 echo $row['rotation'] . "\n";  
}

if($row === FALSE) {
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
    die();
}
```

---

Further note: You originally named the return value of `$stmt->fetch()` `$rows` (plural) instead of `$row`. I'm not sure whether you know that the method will return a single row each time it is called.

Comment: I believe that setting `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` on will throw exception when there is SQL error. $stmt->fetch() returns false when it does not have any row more to fetch. I can be wrong, but this is what I believe.

Comment: I thought this too, but the documentation says: `FALSE is returned on error` That's why there must be an error

Answer (score 1):

What it have to be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013 WHERE thedate=? AND rotation=?";
$data = array('2013-06-03', 1);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();  
var_dump($rows);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sched_main_2013";
$data = array();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array());
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();  
var_dump($rows);
```

If second query returns the rows while first doesn't - there is no data found.
If both returns no rows - then it is caused by **bad database design** which is clearly seen from the table name, which should never have a postfix like this

Comment: -1 because you down-voted my post, again, without leaving a comment and an objective reason.

Comment: Also your answer is very low quality, again. Solves nothing, not worth the memory on servers used to store it